# How to wait for data to finish fetching with async/await in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

**My own answer to the question works, Pedrag's comment which is included in my answer also works**

I am doing a http request call and don't want to display the page until the http response came back (the request call is getRoadmaps). I have a redux state called "loading" to determine if the response came back yet? Any insights on how to implement that in my code? My other redux states are roadmap, which contains an object also called roadmap (sorry for the confusion).

P.S. I saw a few answers that said to do (psuedo code): if not loaded display loading screen else load the normal screen in render. But my problem doesn't exists in render, but in componentWillMount() where I do

```
this.props.getRoadmaps()
```

and then 3 lines later where I do

```
console.log(this.displayRoadmap[0].roadmap[0])
```

which should successfully log the roadmap if getRoadmaps() finished, **it seems like getRoadmaps() is called but then the program continues without getRoadmaps() completely finishes, which causes my displayRoadmap to be undefined. This also leads to some weird phenomenon like if I go from one screen into this component it always works but if I refresh the page it doesn't work**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Tree from "./Tree";
import TreeSidebar from "./TreeSidebar";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getRoadmaps } from "../actions/roadmapAction";
class OneRoadmap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: this.props.roadmap.loading,
      roadmapName: "click a white circle to show more!",
      roadmapImg:
        "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/harmonicons-06/64/plus-circle-512.png",
      roadmapDetail: [{ text: "Click on something" }, { text: "hi" }],
      treeData: //deleted,just the default big json object
   };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getRoadmaps();

    var location1 = this.props.location.pathname;
    var n = location1.slice(9);

    var current_roadmaps = this.props.roadmap.roadmaps;

    this.displayRoadmap = current_roadmaps.filter(
      eachRoadmap => eachRoadmap._id == n
    );
    // now we have a roadmap
    console.log(this.displayRoadmap[0].roadmap[0]);
    this.setState({ treeData: this.displayRoadmap[0].roadmap[0] });
    console.log("is good");
    console.log(this.props.loading);
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  handle_on_click_change = d => {
    this.setState({ roadmapName: d.data.name });
    this.setState({ roadmapImg: d.data.img });
    if (d.data.details == undefined) {
      this.setState({
        roadmapDetail: [{ text: "The author did not put anything here" }]
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ roadmapDetail: d.data.details });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log(this.state.loading)}
        <ul>
          <li styles={{ float: "left" }}>
            <div>
              {console.log(this.state.treeData)}
              <Tree
                on_click_change={this.handle_on_click_change}
                roadmapData={this.state.treeData}
              />
            </div>
          </li>
          <li styles={{ float: "right" }}>
            <div>
              <TreeSidebar
                displayName={this.state.roadmapName}
                displayImg={this.state.roadmapImg}
                displayDetail={this.state.roadmapDetail}
              />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  roadmap: state.roadmap
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getRoadmaps }
)(OneRoadmap);
```

Comment: If `getRoadmaps` returns a promise, you should probably try to async/await on the response

Comment: Thank you @Keno Clayton, I will figure out how to do async right now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, how I do this I use CSS styles I don't know if this if the best approach to do this but it works for me, I will do something like this

```
 this state = {
      loaderStyle: 'block',
      contentStyle: 'none'
 }
componentDidMount() {
    If(this.displayRoadmap[0].length > 0) {
       this.setsState({loaderStyle: 'none', contentStyle: 
          'block:
    } else /// do something

};
```

In my render function, I will do this

```
 <Loader style={{display: this.state.loaderStyle}}/>

 <Content style={{display: this.state.contentStyle}}>. 
 </Content>
```

Comment: Thank you! Clean solution, though I should've specified that my problem wasn't really on the loader but "waiting for my "data fetching to finish before triggering the next line"

Answer (score 1):

First and most important, don't use `componentWillMount`, rather, use `componentDidMount`. `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` is legacy and will be removed in version 17. Now, onto the next issue, you want to start your page off by setting the `loading` state to true.

```
this.state = {
      loading: true,
      roadmapName: "click a white circle to show more!",
      roadmapImg:
        "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/harmonicons-06/64/plus-circle-512.png",
      roadmapDetail: [{ text: "Click on something" }, { text: "hi" }],
      treeData: //deleted,just the default big json object
   };
```

After that, you want to tweak your render method a bit to support conditional rendering:

```
render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <LoadingBar />;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li styles={{ float: 'left' }}>
                        <div>
                            {console.log(this.state.treeData)}
                            <Tree
                                on_click_change={this.handle_on_click_change}
                                roadmapData={this.state.treeData}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li styles={{ float: 'right' }}>
                        <div>
                            <TreeSidebar
                                displayName={this.state.roadmapName}
                                displayImg={this.state.roadmapImg}
                                displayDetail={this.state.roadmapDetail}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Now, whenever your data is ready, you can simply do `this.setState({ loading: false })`, and the render method will return whatever is not the loading bar. So in your specific case:

```
this.setState({ treeData: this.displayRoadmap[0].roadmap[0], loading: false });
```

Comment: Hi @Predrag! I have no problem about the loading screen. The thing is that let's say  in line 58 I call getRoadmaps which goes all the way to database, the code doesn't wait until the response comes back to process to the next line (this.displayRoadmap[0].roadmap[0] which wouldn't work because it isn't returned yet, thank you for helping thought! I think Keno's comment about the "async" will solve my problem, and I will phrase my question better next time:)

Comment: Oh in that case it's true, you definitely want to async/await it. However, why not parse the data as you get it? Something like `fetch('some_url', { method: 'GET' }).then(res = res.json()).then(data => { // some parse here; return parsed}` ? Why fetch and parse in different functions?

Comment: That is definitely the standard way, but I suppose since I am using Redux and I will have to reuse my getRoadmaps() a lot of times, and I have other methods such as deleteItem, getOneRoadmap, and updateRoadmap, it seems more natural to put those functions in different files and functions. Please correct me if my thought process is unconventional :)

Comment: To give such advice would require a bit of deeper system knowledge! But if your entire app requires this data set, and you load it on initial render & store in redux, maybe a good idea is to not render the entire app until the data is ready? We did a complex system once that relied on a whole bunch of redux data that was loaded weird, so we just waited for it, and then let the user play with the app. Eliminates having `if` statements all over the place I guess.

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you mean, did your data fetching take a lot of time so you just straight up set up everything to load first? Anyways, I am going to set up a loading screen while the data fetching is happening right now (not sure if that is what you mean), thanks for all the help!

Comment: It was a weird async system where if I tried to use it while the modules aren't ready it would error out. So I wrapped my app in a loader, waiting for `this.props.module.state` eg to be 'ready', and only then would it load the app. I had two such modules, and one had to wait for the other, so it was simpler to wrap it all up and only access the app when they are both ready. If you explain a bit of how your app works I'd be happy to recommend an approach!

Comment: Cool! May I save this opportunity for later? Gonna be working on the frontend of my website for a while (gosh frontend actually freaks me out more than backend).

Comment: @Acy ahha that's the state of frontend nowadays. Sure, I'm around, feel free to poke or ask a question and shoot the link. It seems scary, but once you get to know it, it's not a big deal!

Answer (score 0):

This can easily achieved by React Higher Order Components as follows.

**withLoadingScreen.js**

```
import * as React from "react";

const withLoadingScreen = WrappedComponent => {
  return class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.loading) return <div className="pre-loader" > Loading... </div>
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};

export default withLoadingScreen;
```

Use HOC as follows with your component

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionCreators),
  withLoadingScreen
)(OneRoadmap)
```

You can pass custom parameters too to the HOC. 
For more example please follow links below. Make changes as you want on your code by referring them.

https://medium.com/@peterpme/learning-higher-order-components-in-react-by-building-a-loading-screen-9f705b89f569

https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/handle-loadings-in-react-by-using-higher-order-components-2ee8de9c3deb

Comment: Thank you for the info! I should've specified my question on the waiting for the roadmaps to return instead of the "loading" stage thing though... The loading thing is minor but the getRoadmap() call doesn't finish before the next line triggers, which will cause problems because I am setting a variable from the results from the getRoadmaps(), I guess I have to ask and dig into async/await as Keno suggested

Answer (score 0):

I checked elraphty's answer because he does answer part of my question and he also wanted me to check his answer. Anyways, if you have trouble **fetching data and waiting for the data to finish fetching**, here's a complete example of how I do it. Predrag Beocanin's comment works:

```
fetch('some_url', { method: 'GET' }).then(res = res.json()).then(data => { // some parse here; return parsed}
```

Here's how I do it (using axios instead of metch, sending request to another completely different file /api/roadmap, and then using Redux to update the store.

In OneRoadmap.js, which is the component I need data fetching in, this is what I call to fetch the data:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
await this.props.getRoadmaps();
.....
}
```

This makes it so that we will run this.props.getRoadmaps() and wait until the line to complete before going to the next line. If you don't put async/await, this.props.getRoadmaps() will trigger but the code in componentDidMount() will immediately continue without this.props.getRoadmaps() to finish data fetching and then updating the state. **Now, ofcourse, Predrag's answer should definitely solve this problem, but just in case you like to place data fetching and state updating with redux in different files (like me), keep reading**.

this is what getRoadmaps() does, which is in a file called RoadmapActions.js:

```
    export const getRoadmaps = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setRoadmapsLoading());
  return axios
    .get("/api/roadmaps")
    .then(res => dispatch({ type: GET_ROADMAPS, payload: res.data }));
};
```

This says that we will send a get request to "/api/roadmaps", then take the return data from the get request, and then send a dispatch to the redux store, which will update the store state and we will ultimately use it in OneRoadmap.js. This is what /api/roadmaps get request returns:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
Roadmap.find()
.sort({ date: -1 })
.then(roadmaps => res.json(roadmaps));
});
```

Roadmap.find() goes into our mongo Database and retrieves all the roadmap items, then we return that to whereever it was called from.

With that returned data, we send a dispatch to the reducer with that data, this is what GET_ROADMAPS() does, GET_ROADMAPS locates in roadmapReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  roadmaps: [],
  loading: false,
  current_roadmap: ""
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {


switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ROADMAPS:
      return {
        ...state,
        roadmaps: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };


}
```

Then, that's it, your redux store state is updated and since I connected OneRoadmap.js with state.roadmap, I can use it freely in the code.